# List of Instance of Object returned in future builder

Tags: json, flutter, dart

In my homescreen:

```
 FutureBuilder(
    future:  getTest.getTest(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      debugPrint("dta: ${snapshot.data}");
      return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
  }
```

This shows:

*[Instance of 'Test', Instance of 'Test']*

I was expecting:

```
[{"id":1,"image":"https://ig.co"},
{"id":2,"image":"https//ft8.co"}]
```

My Object

**Test.dart**

```
@JsonSerializable() 
class Test {
int? id;
String? image;
Test({this.id, this.image});
factory Test.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => 
_$TestFromJson(json);
 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TestToJson(this);
}
```

**Controller.dart**

```
Future<List<Test>> getTest() async {
final result = await authRepository.getNft();
return result;
}
```

**AuthRepository**

```
Future<List<Test>> getNft() async {
try{
  final response = await authApi.getNft();

  final result = (response.data as List)
        .map((e) => Test.fromJson(e))
        .toList();

  return result;
} on DioError catch(e){
  final errorMessage = DioExceptions.fromDioError(e).toString();
  throw errorMessage;
 }
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [toString override](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Object/toString.html) inside the test.dart

```
@JsonSerializable() 
class Test {
  int? id;
  String? image;
  Test({this.id, this.image});
  factory Test.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => 
  _$TestFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TestToJson(this);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{"id": $id, image: "$image"}';
  }
}
```